# Problems starting Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq

I'm trying to use the new [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/) gem in my rails application but when  I run `sidekiq` I get:

```
Booting sidekiq 0.5.1 with Redis at redis://localhost:6379/0
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/task.rb:56: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- control frame ----------
c:0010 p:---- s:0034 b:0034 l:000033 d:000033 CFUNC  :resume
c:0009 p:0018 s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/task.rb:56
c:0008 p:0081 s:0025 b:0025 l:000c40 d:000c40 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:181
c:0007 p:0052 s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 METHOD /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:130
c:0006 p:0061 s:0015 b:0015 l:001db0 d:000014 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:89
c:0005 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 CFUNC  :call
c:0003 p:0021 s:0008 b:0008 l:001f98 d:000007 BLOCK  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/thread_pool.rb:46
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:---- s:0002 b:0002 l:000001 d:000001 TOP   
---------------------------
-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/thread_pool.rb:46:in `block in create'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/thread_pool.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:89:in `block in initialize'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:130:in `run'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:181:in `handle_message'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/task.rb:56:in `resume'
/Users/Kyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@skateparks/gems/celluloid-0.8.0/lib/celluloid/task.rb:56:in `resume'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
0   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x000000010834f51e rb_vm_bugreport + 110
1   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x0000000108243533 report_bug + 259
2   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001082436a1 rb_bug + 161
3   libruby.1.9.1.dylib                 0x00000001082e5fb2 sigbus + 18
4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff967d7cfa _sigtramp + 26

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[1]    1782 abort      sidekiq
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should not be using 1.9.2 for this gem (1.9.3-p0 or higher) and second there is an open issue (GH-26) that references this error.